# This is related to firestore read request. Firestore implemented in android application

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is related to the Firestore read request. Firestore implemented in Android application. Using Firestore with persistence disabled. (offline cache not working) are still Firestore syncing working with Firestore server? What frequency of syncing? Any way to disable syncing?

Answer (score 0):

> Using Firestore with persistence disabled (offline cache not working) are still Firestore syncing working with Firestore server?

If you disable offline persistence it means that you'll no longer have a local copy of the Cloud Firestore database, and you won't be able to access the data when the device is offline. While online, everything will work perfectly fine.

> What frequency of syncing?

You'll be able to sync the data again, only when you regain connectivity.

> Any way to disable syncing?

If you don't have a local cache and you want to disable the syncing with the Firestore server, then what's the benefit of using Firestore in the first place? In my opinion, you should use Firestore for the real-time feature. Remember that Firestore is designed as an online database that came work for short to intermediate periods of being disconnected.